# Package 'Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi,version=15.0.26228.0' failed to install

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am constantly trying to install ASP.NET through the VS2017_community installer.
I've also tried installing Xamarin and WPF but whatever workload requires Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack, the whole installation fails. I was unable to find any solution on any forum, hence this post. Can the community take a look? I am attaching the log file.

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)

Incomplete components
    .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
    SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi,version=15.0.26228.0' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1402
    Impacted workloads
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Impacted components
        .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.26208.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\Uzair3D\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170802114400_002_Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi,version=15.0.26228.0\portablelibrary_dtp_sfx.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  EXTUI="1" 
        Return code: 1402
        Return code details: Could not open key: UNKNOWN\Components\529A8C9116D73655E88ABB96B8E684D0\62168959317C82F33B0E7FC7B549AFBF.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe looking here will help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b14fa15-116e-49a6-b982-1fe40e679d1d/vs-2017-rc-fail-to-installdue-to-multitargeting-pack?forum=vssetup

Comment: Unfortunately, no use :(

Answer (score -1):

I am able to resolve issue using below tool [MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed).

Steps:

1. Problem in installing package.
2. Select package name from list
3. Solution Uninstall package.

After following steps try to install again.